# from one activity create multiple intents which point to different activities gives a nullpointer exception

Tags: android

Can I do sth like that?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btn:
             edit11=edit1.getText().toString();
             edit22=edit2.getText().toString();
             Intent i=new Intent(this,selection.class);
             i.putExtra("code_value",edit11);
             Intent k=new Intent(this,myservice.class);
             k.putExtra("time_value",edit22);
                     this.startService(k);
             Intent l=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);

             startActivity(l);  
             break;

     }
     }
```

From the above activity which has 2 edit text fields and a button I want when the button is pressed to pass the "code_value" to selection activity , time_value to myservice activity and start main activity.

Doing that gives me a nullpointer exception in selection activity oncreate.
I must mention that if I use only Intent i and pass the 2 values in it and then startactivity(i),it works fine.

---------------------UPDATE------------------------------------------

Selection class:

```
public class selection extends FragmentActivity implements OnMyLocationChangeListener{

    GoogleMap googleMap;
    double latitude=0.0;  
    double longitude=0.0;
    String code_value="";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.selection);


        code_value=getIntent().getExtras().getString("code_value");
         ...//code for google map
      ...
      public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if(checkedId == R.id.rb_normal){
                    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
         ....
          else if(checkedId == R.id.save_location){

                 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {

                           postData(Double.toString(latitude),Double.toString(longitude),code_value);
                     }

                 }).start();
        .....
         public void postData(String lat, String lo ,String code) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet  htget = new HttpGet("www.test.com"+lat+"/"+lo+"/"+code);

    try {
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(htget);
        String resp = response.getStatusLine().toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, resp, 5000).show();


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error", 5000).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error", 5000).show();
    }
```

Logcat:

```
W/dalvikvm(2459): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aacc560)
03-28 10:34:35.478: E/AndroidRuntime(2459): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-28 10:34:35.498: W/System.err(2459): java.io.IOException: Permission denied
03-28 10:34:35.508: E/AndroidRuntime(2459): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 10:34:35.508: E/AndroidRuntime(2459): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.datagps/com.example.datagps.selection}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 10:34:35.508: E/AndroidRuntime(2459):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
03-28 10:34:35.508: E/AndroidRuntime(2459):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-28 10:34:35.508: E/AndroidRuntime(2459):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-28 10:34:35.508: E/AndroidRuntime(2459):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-28 10:34:35.508: E/AndroidRuntime(2459):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-28 10:34:35.508: E/AndroidRuntime(2459):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-28 10:34:35.508: E/AndroidRuntime(2459):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-28 10:34:35.508: E/AndroidRuntime(2459):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 10:34:35.508: E/AndroidRuntime(2459):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-28 10:34:35.508: E/AndroidRuntime(2459):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:895)
03-28 10:34:35.508: E/AndroidRuntime(2459):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653)
03-28 10:34:35.508: E/AndroidRuntime(2459):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 10:34:35.508: E/AndroidRuntime(2459): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 10:34:35.508: E/AndroidRuntime(2459):     at com.example.datagps.selection.<init>(selection.java:87)
03-28 10:34:35.508: E/AndroidRuntime(2459):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-28 10:34:35.508: E/AndroidRuntime(2459):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
03-28 10:34:35.508: E/AndroidRuntime(2459):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
03-28 10:34:35.508: E/AndroidRuntime(2459):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
```

**I forgot to out in manifest the " ".
After that , when I start my application it crashes giving "nullpointer exception in IntentService".**

Comment: please add here java code of selection class.

Comment: @George : where is line number 87 in selection.java?

Comment: @prasperK:String code_value=getIntent().getExtras().getString("code_value");

Comment: @prasperK:I have it below double longitude

Comment: @George : i think u will need to use `startActivity(i);`  instead of `startActivity(l);`  this for starting selection Activity?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK:Sorry , I messed up a little.I had the string in another position.Now it's ok!I am updating.But I receive nullpointer exception in myservice class (refering to the other post)

Comment: @George : ok plz update your question with latest code and logcat result to get more help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27082/discussion-between--k-and-george)

Comment: @prasperK:Ok , this post is over!I had wrong position of string.I will answer it.Please scheck the other post.I have nullpointer in myservice.Thanks

Comment: @prasperK:It doesn;t load the page in chat..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that I had the code_value string before the oncreate.Moved it and its ojk now.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot start your `HttpClient` in the main UI thread. You must create another Thread/Runnable in which to run your `httpClient`. In addition to your `NullPointerException` (once you solve that), you are going to receive a `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Move the `httpClient` into a `Runnable` to fix part of your problem.

In order to fix the `NullPointerException`, we need to see the LogCat showing the file and line number in which it occurs. You must post the line of code at that line number, because we cannot see line numbers in the question.

Comment: :Ok, I updated.(I had postData inside runnable).The postdata is right?I want to send 3 strings as one at http.Thanks

Comment: Yes. The way you moved `postData()` into a `Runnable` is ok. You probably should display a `ProgressBar` before you call `postData()` and then take it down when `postData()` completes. Beware, you cannot `dismiss()` the `ProgressBar` from within `postData()` because it is not on the UI Thread anymore. You will have to redirect to the UI Thread with a `Handler` to close the `ProgressBar`.